# Can i parameterize the url in the generated Files by SvcUtil.exe?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am using [SvcUtil](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/framework/wcf/servicemodel-metadata-utility-tool-svcutil-exe) to generate files to communicate with SOAP-Services.
The generated file has mutliple classes and interfaces.
In the files the target url is stored as a plain string at multiple points in method and class decorators like this:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.1.0")]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://someurl/somename.wsdl")] //This url should be a parameter i want to read from appsettings.
public partial class Faulttype{.......
```

Now in testing ths url is different than in production. Everything else is exactly the same. I wonder how i can change change this url to a parameter that i can read it from an appsettings file. Normally my favourite way to go would be to use DI to get inject an Optionobject and read the parameter from that but but i think this will not work here.
How can i change the files so the string in all the decorators is not hardcoded?

Comment: Namespace UR*I*s should be fixed by the service, and unrelated to any UR*L* you might be using to access instances of the service. There shouldn't be a need to vary these, assuming the services have been configured competently. I.e. they're a fixed part of the "contract" that the service provides.

Comment: yes but they are not configured competently. I cant change that.

Comment: Well, the tools aren't built to deal with that. You need to discuss with the service providers why they cannot produce a stable interface based on namespaces. I.e. They're not conforming to standard norms, no sane consumer will be able to use their services

Answer (score 0):

You can parameterize the URLs/ports by creating a batch file like that:

```
set Host=localhost
svcutil.exe http://%Host%/Service1?wsdl
... other svcutil parameters
```

If you need, you can pass the Host value as a parameter to the batch file.